# Oren-Nayar Reflectance

Tags: raytracing, brdf, diffuse

I'm trying to implement Oren-Nayar reflectance and I don't quite understand the Wikipedia article on it.

In the article, it has this diagram:

[image]

I can't figure out what $(\theta_i, \phi_i)$ and $(\theta_r, \phi_r)$ represent. They are used in the equation.

Thank you!

Comment: The spherical coordinate angles defining the direction towards the light, and towards the eye.